# MC Realms on PE - How do you do it?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition, minecraft-bedrock-edition-realms

I'm in Meopham and I'm trying to connect to someone in Longfield and we're not on the same wifi. I've looked it up on various websites and they have all said that you should use realms. Is this true and if so is it possible to access it here? We've tried connecting to servers and we can't get on the same port. I think my external reach to servers has been blocked since I have somebody younger than me in the household (he's in primary) and we don't want him interacting freely with any strangers, especially if the chat's not moderated.

Comment: I don't think that's how Realms works.

Answer (score 1):

As of right now, Minecraft Pocket Edition does not have Realms. There are [unofficial versions](https://www.pocketmine.net/) but these are nowhere near complete to the normal game via Wi-Fi.

If you cannot connect to external servers, there is no way to connect to any unofficial servers.